# Trying to add image in Git add but keep getting the following message? I tried restarting/reloading git and closing VS Code but nothing worked

Tags: css, git, image, github

[image]

That is:

```sh
hashanp@DESKTOP-9E00J4S: ~/cats-cakes$ git add .
error: open("img/cake.jpg"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file img/cake.jpg 
fatal: adding files failed
```

Trying to add image in Git add but keep getting the following message? I tried restarting/reloading git and closing VS Code but nothing worked.

Comment: Seems like your user doesn't have access to the file. Can you run cat on it, as a simple test?

Comment: It would also benefit everyone if you copy&paste the error message as text, rather than a screenshot. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a git bash session on Windows, or a WSL session.

If you can not easily identify the process which keeps an handle to that file, preventing another program (like `git`) to access it, I would:

- reboot
- restart my git bash or WSL2 session
- try to add `img/cake.jpg` before opening any IDE.

Since it is an Ubuntu session, I would also try, for tesdting:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 img
```

That way, the folder `img` will be accessible.

Comment: hashanp@DESKTOP-9EOOJ4S:~/cats-cakes$ git add .
error: open("img/cake.jpg"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file img/cake.jpg
fatal: adding files failed         Thanx for your reply. I tried what you said but still get the same message.

Comment: hashanp@DESKTOP-9EOOJ4S:~$ cd cats-cakes
hashanp@DESKTOP-9EOOJ4S:~/cats-cakes$ cat
                                                                                                                                (blinker)                                                                                     I did it and this is what I got. I am new to Git. Thanx for your help.

Comment: @Devbreaker29 The git add fails right after a reboot? What version of Git are you using? Are you on Windows? Is it a git bash or a WSL2 session?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS @VonC

Comment: @Devbreaker29 OK. For testing, can you try and do a `sudo chmod -R 755 img`? Then try and add again.

Comment: Great. Thanx for your help.